# Grails 6.1.0 (and) Intellij 2023.2.5 Ultimate problems

Tags: intellij-idea, grails

I wanted to start a new project with Intellij (2023.2.5 Ultimate with grails plugin) and grails 6.1.0 and Java 11.

In Intellij I got an error creating the project (missing init in <I forgot>).
Then I started the creation of the project via command-line with grails via

```
grails create-app ArtDB --servlet=tomcat
```

where I got the following error-message

```
| Warning Unrecognized flag: servlet.
| Application created at /Volumes/SanDiskExtreme1/Users/susanne/Projects/ArtDB
```

when I open this created project in Intellij, I got the following

```
class [Ljava.io.File; cannot be cast to class java.io.File ([Ljava.io.File; and java.io.File are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
class [Ljava.io.File; cannot be cast to class java.io.File ([Ljava.io.File; and java.io.File are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

a bit lost at the moment, maybe I should stick with grails 5 at the moment?

Update 23.Nov. 2023:

Even using the EAP Version of IntelliJ, I got the following errors using the Grails-Application-Forge for a new project:

[image]

Comment: Please try 2023.3 version.

Comment: Even with 2023.3, I got errors in using the Grails-Application-Forge Type from "New->Project"

Comment: Is this an intellij problem? What happens if you do ```grails create-app ArtDB``` from the command line?